# How can I get a DataGrid to unselect on click when SelectionMode="Extended"?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

The default behaviour of a WPF `DataGrid` is to select when a row is clicked if `SelectionMode="Extended"` which is what I want, however I also wish for the row to un-select if it was previously already selected when clicked.

I have tried the following which will unselect the row as soon as it's selected, it seems the row selection occurs before the mouse click event.

```
private void DoGridMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args) {
    // Get source row.
    DependencyObject source = (DependencyObject)args.OriginalSource;
    var row = source.FindParent<DataGridRow>();
    if (row == null)
        return;
    // If selected, unselect.
    if (row.IsSelected) {
        row.IsSelected = false;
        args.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Where I am binding to this event with the following grid.

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Extended"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          MouseLeftButtonUp="DoGridMouseLeftButtonUp">
```

Comment: shouldnt it be up to the user to unselect the previous selected row? the user can do this by simply click "Ctrl"+"leftMousebutton"?

Comment: I missed the datagrid tag, sorry for that.

Comment: @blindmeis - ordinarily that would be fine, however the WPF `DataGrid` is not standard in its behaviour where controls usually require CTRL+CLICK for both addition and removal, `DataGrid` requires CTRL for subtraction only. Our target audience is for simple people who will find it much simpler to just simply click a row to select/unselect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by instead of handling events on the grid itself to handle them on the cell instead, this involves an event setter for `DataGridCell` as follows:

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Extended"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                         Handler="DoCheckRow"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <!-- Column mapping omitted. -->
</DataGrid>
```

Event handler code.

```
public void DoCheckRow(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
    if (cell != null && !cell.IsEditing) {
        DataGridRow row = FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>(cell);
        if (row != null) {
            row.IsSelected = !row.IsSelected;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

My grid is read only so any edit behavior is ignored here.

Comment: This works, but when I add a Button to a CellTemplate, its event isnt fired because we're setting e.Handled = true. Any idea's how to work around this?

Comment: I was able to solve my problem. Question / answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12113645/71904

Comment: Excellent, I was thinking of mentioning something similar, I didn't have a windows computer handy to test first though, glad to hear it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

my wpf datagrid requires CTRL+CLICK for both addition and removal of MULTIPLE rows. so its standard behavior ;) but nevertheless, why you dont use the PreviewMouseDown event and then check for leftmousebutton and Ctrl and do your unselect logic and set e.handled=true?

Comment: Odd, I don't need to press CTRL for addition (.NET 4). I will check the preview event tonight, thanks.

Comment: well thats strange is use .net4 too and if i want to select every third row for example i need to use CTRL.

Comment: Rasing cancel on `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` causes the same behavior as the non preview event where it will unselect right after it was selected. I do have a solution though.