# Chosing datagrid event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So I have a WPF application and a datagrid in it, uneditable, with full row selecting enabled, and I'm trying to make a kind of toggle on-off functionality with the datagrid rows. However, I can't seem to find the appropriate Event for a simple row selection. There's `SelectionChanged`, which doesn't work if I click again on the already selected item. There's simple `Click` (many types of them), but all of them happen BEFORE the row is actually selected, so if I try to get selected item on the click I will get null. There is some other Event (that I forgot about) that requires to click twice, which is not really what I want. I'm running out of ideas, maybe there's some good event-combination or some way to override them or maybe I'm just missing something?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the information you have given, @Yatrix's solution is perfectly valid!

But to that you have responded ..

> Happens before the row is selected, so doesn't work :/

Then there is something you are missing here. Even if LeftMouseDown \ LeftMouseUp \ PreviewLeftMouseDown \ Up events occur before selection event, they would know if the row is already selected or not. That way they can deselect it and then do

```
e.Handled=true
```

.... so that selection is never called after mouse events thus the reselection is avoided.

Try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`PreviewMouseDown` or `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` may help. I also found this on this site that may provide you with direction:

[How can I get a DataGrid to unselect on click when SelectionMode="Extended"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465178/how-can-i-get-a-datagrid-to-unselect-on-click-when-selectionmode-extended)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sign up for the row Selected event you'll need to do it for each row in the DataGrid. Try signing up for the [LoadingRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.loadingrow%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event on the DataGrid and for each row sign up for the [Selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.selected) event.